# db2 ? lookup error db2 error code

Tags: db2

I don’t know which is the shortest way to look at the error descriptions like “ERRORCODE=-4463, SQLSTATE=42601”
Generally I google such kind of error descriptions and I can get the result somewhat anyways.
But this turns out to be very inefficient, sometimes it is just difficult to get description regarding the error code and sql state.
I know the db2 built in command like : db2 ? SQL0443N  will provide information about specific  SQLCODE
But when encountered error description like that above , how do I turn that into a SQLCODE, so that I can lookup it quickly using db2 ?

Comment: I _thought_ the 4-digit number was the SQLCODE, although I could be wrong about that (it is for the iSeries version).  Does the command not work if you pass it an `SQLSTATE`?  If I'm remembering right, the only real difference between states and codes is that states are supposed to be universal, while codes tend to be vendor-defined (although there are some commonalities).  There's also a [listing](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc%2Fdoc%2Frdb2stt.html) online, which may help.

Comment: @X-Zero , I know I can get the final answers online, but I was just trying to provide more information about the failure quickly. just passing the SQLSTATE to the command doesn't works.

Comment: @X-Zero seems passing the SQLSTATE works now, weird. maybe I made some stupid mistakes.

Comment: yep, encountered this again.
$db2 ? 08001

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what @Clockwork-Muse commented is definitely correct.

and I am now referring to these documents for the SQL codes and states. hmm neat

[SQL ERROR CODE LOOKUP](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n440.htm)

[SQL STATE CODE LOOKUP](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc/doc/rdb2stt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link with different DB2 error codes https://urssanj00.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/db2-sql-error-code-and-description/

This saved me tons of hours!